# how can I insert a button in grid cell?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

The following works in Delphi XE5 if you want a cell to display a button.
However, in Delphi XE6 it doesn't.

```
Type
    TSimpleLinkCell = class(TTextCell)
    protected
        FButton: TSpeedButton;
        procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    public
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); reintroduce;
    end;

constructor TSimpleLinkCell.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
    Self.TextAlign := TTextAlign.taLeading;
    FButton := TSpeedButton.Create(Self);
    FButton.Parent := Self;
    FButton.Height := 16;
    FButton.Width := 16;
    FButton.Align := TAlignLayout.alRight;
    FButton.OnClick := ButtonClick;
end;
```

How can i make the above work in Delphi XE6?

Comment: I've tested the answer you have and it works. Can you say that it's the correct response? Please!

Answer (score 1):

1. Your SpeedButton has no text so nothing will be displayed until you went into the button with the mouse
2. If you make TColumn type which inserted this object into the grid, it will work. Here is fully working example of your code (tested on XE4):

   ```
   unit Unit5;

   interface

   uses
     System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Rtti, System.Classes,
     System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs,
     FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Grid;

   type
     TSimpleLinkCell = class(TTextCell)
     protected
         FButton: TSpeedButton;
         procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
      public
         constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); reintroduce;
     end;

     TButtonColumn=class(TColumn)
     protected
       function CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;override;
     end;

     TForm5 = class(TForm)
       Grid1: TGrid;
       procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
     private
       { Private declarations }
     public
       { Public declarations }
     end;

   var
     Form5: TForm5;

   implementation
   {$R *.fmx}

   constructor TSimpleLinkCell.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
   begin
       inherited Create(AOwner);
       Self.TextAlign := TTextAlign.taLeading;
       FButton := TSpeedButton.Create(Self);
       FButton.Parent := Self;
       FButton.Height := 16;
       FButton.Width := 16;
       FButton.Align := TAlignLayout.alRight;
       FButton.OnClick := ButtonClick;
   //    FButton.Text:='Button';
   end;

   procedure TSimpleLinkCell.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     ShowMessage('The button is clicked!');
   end;

   function TButtonColumn.CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;
   var
     cell:TSimpleLinkCell;
   begin
     cell:=TSimpleLinkCell.Create(Self);
     Result:=cell;
   end;

   procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Grid1.AddObject(TButtonColumn.Create(Grid1));
   end;

   end.
   ```